# First bitcoins and confused

Tags: transactions

I have bought bitcoins on https://www.bitcoin.de/en/btc_address. However, I  don't know how to transfer them to a bitcoin wallet or why I need a bitcoin wallet

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange! Hopefully, I succeeded in answering your question, otherwise additional comments from you could help me to better understand what your needs are. If your question was answered you can accept the answer best suited to your needs, signaling that you are satisfied. If you are interested in finding out more about how Stackexchange works, you can read the [about page linked in the header](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: With a few minutes of research on your own should be able to figure this out. I'd start with the FAQ on the site you bought the coins on. I really wonder why you bought something you don't know what to do with. Sounds like throwing away money to me.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the Bitcoins that you bought are being kept by Bitcoin.de for you.

Assuming, that you bought the Bitcoins in order to use them as payment medium or investment, it seems likely that you would want to move them to your control.

There are two different kinds of wallets: Wallets offered by online services, which you access much like online banking, and personal wallets that you directly save on your computer or smartphone. In general wallets are storage tools for keeping funds, much like their physical counterparts.

In any case it is important to create a backup of your wallet, as Bitcoins are lost when you lose access to the wallet.

There are many different services that offer online wallets and several different programs for your personal computer that allow you to create a wallet for yourself, for example the [original Bitcoin Client](http://bitcoin.org/de/download).
Once you have acquired a wallet, you should be able to determine an address to which you can withdraw the funds that Bitcoin.de currently keeps for you. [Coindesk has a section in it's getting started guide about the storage of Bitcoin.](http://www.coindesk.com/information/how-to-store-your-bitcoins/)

However, –I hope this doesn't sound too blunt– I would suggest that you find out a bit more about how Bitcoin works and what you want to do with them before you start experimenting, as it would be tragic if you accidentally lost your bitcoins.

You can find a [Getting started Guide here.](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Getting_started)